# UIActivityIndicatorView show when loading iCloud document in iOS

Tags: ios, icloud, uiactivityindicatorview

In my app , i am using `iCloud`.

I want to show `UIActivityIndicatorView` when loading `iCloud` Document into my `UITextView` and after finished i want to hide `UIActivityIndicatorView`.

How can i check iCloud Document Loading and finished to show `UIActivityIndicatorView`?

Here is my code to load iCloud document into my `UITextView`.

```
[doc openWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
                if(success)
                {
                    self.txtView.text = self.doc.noteContent;
                }

                else
                {
                    NSLog(@"Error");
                }
            }];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is as simple as:

```
[self.myActivityIndicator startAnimating];
[doc openWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
            [self.myActivityIndicator stopAnimating];
            if(success)
            {
                self.txtView.text = self.doc.noteContent;
            }

            else
            {
                NSLog(@"Error");
            }
        }];
```